# Pourquoi n'y a-t-il pas de « à propos de ce site » dans notre menu bandeau ?

Tags: support, about-page

Les autres sites de Stack Exchange que j'ai eu l'occasion de regarder ont un lien vers la page *about* du site dans le menu du bandeau. Ce n'est pas le cas pour *French Language*. Et pourtant [la page existe](https://french.stackexchange.com/about).

Y a-t-il une raison à cela ?

---

All other Stack Exchange sites I've had a look at, have an "about" link in the top menu. That's not the case for *French Language*, why ? The [page exists](https://french.stackexchange.com/about), though.

Comment: Il n'apparait que sur les sites sur lesquels les utilisateurs ne sont pas identifiés. Est-ce que cela élucide la question ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: non parce que je vois le *about* sur tous les autres sites où je suis identifiée !

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: et je viens de regarder FL&U d'un navigateur sans m'identifier et il n'y a pas de « about ».

Comment: Ah, je vois. Ok, ce bandeau-là !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Le lien « about » dans la barre du haut n'apparaît que jusqu'à 1500 rep (5000 rep sur les sites qui ne sont plus en bêta). La justification est qu'à ce stade, l'utilisateur a suffisamment l'habitude du site pour ne pas avoir besoin de consulter cette page souvent. Le lien apparaît en bas (entre le contenu et le menu de sites).

Pour un visiteur non identifié, il n'y a pas de lien « about » dans la barre du haut, mais le gros bouton « Tell me more » sur la page d'accueil amène à la même page.

---

See [Where is the 'about' link for Sports.SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190873/where-is-the-about-link-for-sports-se)